# How to disable Default XML validation in eclipse with preferences file?

Tags: xml, eclipse

How to define Eclipse preferences file in order to disable XML validation by default. This is a follow-up of [Disable XML validation in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489510) question. Any help is appreciated.